# How do I add a new dependency to a Clojure project using emacs or lein?

Tags: clojure, dependency-management, leiningen, spacemacs

I use emacs (to be more precise, Spacemacs), and so far, I haven't seen any way to add a project dependency (say, ring or hiccup) to my project, other than opening ./project.clj and adding a new vector to `:dependencies`. I'm not feeling comfortable doing this because I need to remember exact version of the package I want to add as a dependency, and multiplied by possible number of these packages, this amount of information is clearly not for a human head. Meanwhile, I have a strong feeling that it's possible to add a project dependency either via CLI or in emacs directly (perhaps Cider?). Is it possible, and how do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28505847/1860180

Comment: lein-plz is nice and actually solves the problem. However, I got the answer (and accepted it) that reflected the most interesting point: adding dependency without leaving emacs at all. Anyway, thanks for a tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spacemacs you can use `clj-refactor` to help you with this. Navigate to your `project.clj`, `cider jack-in` with `,'` and press `,rap` (major mode, **r**efactor, **a**dd, **p**roject dependency) for `cljr-add-project-dependency`.

In the menu you can search for an artifact available in Clojars:

[image: Choose artifact]

and select one of the available versions:

[image: Choose version]

When you press enter the dependency is added to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Not for the op, but for others, this won't work if you're using deps.edn and not lein.

Answer (score 1):

Managing this by hand is not difficult. As you said you simply open your project.clj file in your editor and add dependencies.

You can find the current version by either checking the project's page or by searching for it on clojars' or maven's website. If you know what you need it only takes a few minutes, and if you're not writing throw away code a few minutes is nothing compared to the life of the project.

To maintain dependencies, something like [lein ancient](https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient) is very helpful.